# Trying to use a variable as label in ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm not sure what's going on here, but when I try to run ggplots, it tells me that u and u1 are not valid lists.  Did I enter u and u1 incorrectly, that it thinks these are functions, did I forget something, or did I enter things wrong into ggplots?

```
u1            <- function(x,y){max(utilityf1(x))}


utilityc1 <- data.frame("utilityc1" = 
                          u(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20),
                                     c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20)))
utilityc1 <- data.frame("utilityc1" = 
                          u1(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20),
                                     c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20)))

hhcomp <- data.frame(
   pqx, pqy, utility, hours, p1qx, p1qy, utilit, utilityc1, 
   utilityc, u,u1, o, o1, o2
)

library(ggplot2)

 ggplot(hhcomp, aes(x=utility, y=consumption))+
   coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 16) )+
        ylim(0,20)+
           labs(x = "leisure(hours)",y="counsumption(units)")+

                     geom_line(aes(x = u, y = consumption))+

                     geom_line(aes(x = u1, y = consumption))
```

I'm not sure what else to explain, so if someone could provide some help on providing code to stack overflow that would be useful.  I'm also not sure how much of a description to have, I should have enough code to be reproducible, but there is a problem that Stack Overflow only allows so much code, so it would be good to know the right amount to add.

Comment: Your code is not completely reproducible. There is no definition for `u`, or most of the values assigned to `hhcomp`. Please add definitions for these values or just enough that is needed for the ggplot error you are receiving. That being said, the assignment for `u` and `u1` should be correct so long as they are in the column headers of `hhcomp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to read the documentation for `ggplot2` and maybe `r` in general.

## data.frame

For starters, a `data.frame` object is a collection of vectors appended together column wise. Most of what you have defined as inputs for `hhcomp` are functions, which cannot be stored as a `data.frame`. A canonical example of a data frame in r is `iris`

```
head(iris)
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

str(iris) #print the structure of an r object
#'data.frame':  150 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
# $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
# $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
# $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
# $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

## functions

There is a lot going on with your functions. Nested functions are fine, but it seems as though you are failing to pass all values on. This probably means you are trying to apply R's scoping rules but this makes code ambiguous of where values are found.

With the currently defined functions, calling `u(1:2,3:4)` passes `1:2` to `utilityf` but `utilityf`'s y argument is never assigned (but with r's lazy evaluation we reach a different error before r realizes that this value is missing). The next function that gets evaluated in this nest is `p1qyf` which is defined as follows

```
p1qyf <- function(y){(w1*16)-(w1*x)}
```

with this definition, it does not matter what you pass to the argument `y` it will never be used and will always return the same thing.

```
#with only the function defined
p1qyf()
#Error in p1qyf() : object 'w1' not found
#defining w1
w1 <- 1.5
p1qyf()
#Error in p1qyf() : object 'x' not found
x <- 10:20
#All variables defined in the function 
#can now be found in the global environment
#thus the function can be called with no errors because
#w1 and x are defined somewhere...

p1qyf() #nothing assigned to y
[1]  9.0  7.5  6.0  4.5  3.0  1.5  0.0 -1.5 -3.0 -4.5 -6.0
p1qyf(y = iris) #a data.frame assigned to y
[1]  9.0  7.5  6.0  4.5  3.0  1.5  0.0 -1.5 -3.0 -4.5 -6.0
p1qyf(y = foo_bar) #an object that hasn't even been assigned yet
[1]  9.0  7.5  6.0  4.5  3.0  1.5  0.0 -1.5 -3.0 -4.5 -6.0
```

I imagine you actually intend to define it this way

```
p1qyf <- function(y){(w1*16)-(w1*y)}
#Now what we pass to it affects the output
p1qyf(1:10)
#[1] 22.5 21.0 19.5 18.0 16.5 15.0 13.5 12.0 10.5  9.0
head(p1qyf(iris))
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1        16.35       18.75        21.90        23.7      NA
#2        16.65       19.50        21.90        23.7      NA
#3        16.95       19.20        22.05        23.7      NA
#4        17.10       19.35        21.75        23.7      NA
#5        16.50       18.60        21.90        23.7      NA
#6        15.90       18.15        21.45        23.4      NA
```

You can improve this further by defining more arguments so that R doesn't need to search for missing values with it's [scoping rules](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/scoping-rules-of-r.html)

```
p1qyf <- function(y, w1 = 1.5){(w1*16)-(w1*y)} 
#w1 is defaulted to 1.5 and doesn't need to be searched for.
```

I would spend some time looking into your functions because they are unclear and some, such as your `p1qyf`, do not fully use the arguments they are passed.

## ggplot

ggplot takes some type of structured data object such as `data.frame` `tbl_df`, and allows plotting. The `aes` mappings can take the symbol names of the column headers you wish to map. Continuing with `iris` as an example.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species))+
    geom_point() +
    geom_line()
```

I hope this helps clears up why you may be getting some errors. Honestly though, if you were actually able to declare a data.frame then the problem here is that your post is still not that reproducible. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

````
pqxf      <- function(x){(1)*(y)} # replace 1 with py and assign a value to py
pqyf      <- function(y){(w * 16)-(w * x)} # 
utilityf  <- function(x, y) { (pqyf(x)) * ((pqxf(y)))} # the utility function C,l
hours     <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20)
w1         <- 1.5 
p1qxf      <- function(x){(1)*(y)} # replace 1 with py and assign a value to p1y
p1qyf      <- function(y){(w1 * 16)-(w1 * x)} # 
utilityf1  <- function(x, y) { (p1qyf(x)) * ((p1qxf(y)))} # the utility function (C,l)
utilitycf   <- function(x,y){max(utilityf(x))/((pqyf(y)))}
utilityc1f  <- function(x,y){max(utilityf1(x))/((pqyf(y)))}
u             <- function(x,y){max(utilityf(x))}
u1            <- function(x,y){max(utilityf1(x))}```
````